# How to generate data for gaussian distributions in these 2 scenarios in R?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

In "Elements of Statistical Learning" by Tibshirani, when comparing least squares/linear models and knn these 2 scenarios are stated:

> Scenario 1: The training data in each class were generated from bivariate Gaussian distributions with uncorrelated components and different means.
>
> Scenario 2: The training data in each class came from a mixture of 10
>   low- variance Gaussian distributions, with individual means themselves
>   distributed as Gaussian.

The idea is that the first is better suited for least squares/linear models and the second for knn like models (those with higher variance from what i understand since knn takes into account the closest points and not all points).

In R, how would I simulate data for both scenarios?

The end goal is to be able to reproduce both scenarios in order to prove  that effectively the 1st one is better explained by the linear model than the 2nd one.

Thanks!

Comment: Although this question has a statistical component--it would be of interest to explain the distinction between the two scenarios--its emphasis on `R` has caused it to collect purely programming-oriented answers, making it off-topic on CV.

Comment: I actually want to be able to reproduce the 2 scenarios in order to better understand the differences and how they apply to linear models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be scenario 1

```
library(mvtnorm)

N1 = 50
N2 = 50
K = 2

mu1 = c(-1,3)
mu2 = c(2,0)

cov1 = 0
v11 = 2
v12 = 2
Sigma1 = matrix(c(v11,cov1,cov1,v12),nrow=2)

cov2 = 0
v21 = 2
v22 = 2
Sigma2 = matrix(c(v21,cov2,cov2,v22),nrow=2)

x1 = rmvnorm(N1,mu1,Sigma1)
x2 = rmvnorm(N2,mu2,Sigma2)
```

This could be a candidate for simulating from a Gaussian mixture:

```
BartSimpson <- function(x,n = 100){ 
   means <- as.matrix(sort(rnorm(10)))
   dens <- .1*rowSums(apply(means,1,dnorm,x=x,sd=.1)) 
   rBartSimpson <- c(apply(means,1,rnorm,n=n/10,sd=.1))
   return(list("thedensity" = dens,"draws" = rBartSimpson))
}

x <- seq(-5,5,by=.01)

plot(x,BartSimpson(x)$thedensity,type="l",lwd=4,col="yellow2",xlim=c(-4,4),ylim=c(0,0.6))
```

Comment: Thanks :) Why the sort?

Comment: may well be superfluous, I was fixing something and tried this, but that was not the point, as it turned out

Answer (score 1):

In the code below, I first create the 10 different means of the classes, and then use the means to draw random values from those means. The code is identical for the two scenarios, but you'll have to adjust the variance within and between classes to get the results you want.

Scenario 1:

Here you want to generate 10 classes with different means (I assume the means follow a bivariate gaussian distribution). The difference between classes is much less than the difference within classes.

```
library(MASS)
n <- 20
# subjects per class
classes <- 10
# number of classes
mean <- 100
# mean value for all classes
var.between <- 25
# variation between classes
var.within <- 225
# variation within classes
covmatrix1 <- matrix(c(var.between,0,0,var.between), nrow=2)
# covariance matrix for the classes
means <- mvrnorm(classes, c(100,100), Sigma=covmatrix1)
# creates the means for the two variables for each class using variance between classes
covmatrix2 <- matrix(c(var.within,0,0,var.within), nrow=2)
# creates a covariance matrix for the subjects
class <- NULL
values <- NULL
for (i in 1:10) {
  temp <- mvrnorm(n, c(means[i], means[i+classes]), Sigma=covmatrix2)
  class <- c(class, rep(i, n))
values <- c(values, temp)
}
# this loop uses generates data for each class based on the class means and variance within classes
valuematrix <- matrix(values, nrow=(n*classes))
data <- data.frame (class, valuematrix)
plot(data$X1, data$X2)
```

Alternatively, if you don't care about specifying the variance between the classes, and you don't want any correlation within classes, you can just do this:

```
covmatrix <- matrix(c(225, 0, 0, 225), nrow=2)
# specifies that the variance in both groups is 225 and no covariance
values <- matrix(mvrnorm(200, c(100,100), Sigma=covmatrix), nrow=200)
# creates a matrix of 200 individuals with two values each.
```

Scenario 2:

Here the only difference is that the variation between classes is larger than the variation within classes. Try exchanging the value of the variable var.between to around 500 and the variable var.within to 25 and you'll see a clear clustering in the scatterplot:

```
n <- 20
# subjects per class
classes <- 10
# number of classes
mean <- 100
# mean value for all classes
var.between <- 500
# variation between classes
var.within <- 25
# variation within classes
covmatrix1 <- matrix(c(var.between,0,0,var.between), nrow=2)
# covariance matrix for the classes
means <- mvrnorm(classes, c(100,100), Sigma=covmatrix1)
# creates the means for the two variables for each class using variance between classes
covmatrix2 <- matrix(c(var.within,0,0,var.within), nrow=2)
# creates a covariance matrix for the subjects
class <- NULL
values <- NULL
for (i in 1:10) {
  temp <- mvrnorm(n, c(means[i], means[i+classes]), Sigma=covmatrix2)
  class <- c(class, rep(i, n))
values <- c(values, temp)
}
# this loop uses generates data for each class based on the class means and variance within classes
valuematrix <- matrix(values, nrow=(n*classes))
data <- data.frame (class, valuematrix)
plot(data$X1, data$X2)
```

The plot should confirm that the data are clustered.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was expecting that scenario 1 would be better explained by applying linear model (model = lm(X2~X1, data=data)) than scenario 2 but that does not seem to be true although I do see that in scenario 2 the data is clustered. Even changing the var.betweeen and var.within in scenario 1 to low values (eg 2) does not seem to consistently provide better p-values for the linear model in  scenario 1. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know much about knn models. I was mostly trying to help with generating the data.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from both answers here I ended up using this:

```
mixed_dists = function(n, n_means, var=0.2) {
    means = rnorm(n_means, mean=1, sd=2)
    values <- NULL
    class <- NULL
    for (i in 1:n_means) {
        temp <- rnorm(n/n_means, mean=means[i], sd=0.2)
        class <- c(class, rep(i, n/n_means))
        values <- c(values, temp)
    }
    return(list(values, class));
}

N = 100

#Scenario 1: The training data in each class were generated from bivariate Gaussian distributions 
#with uncorrelated components and different means.
scenario1 = function () { 
    var = 0.5
    n_groups = 2
    m = mixed_dists(N, n_groups, var=var)
    x = m[[1]]
    group = m[[2]]
    y = mixed_dists(N, n_groups, var=var)[[1]]
    data = matrix(c(x,y, group), nrow=N, ncol=3)
    colnames(data) = c("x", "y", "group")
    data = data.frame(data)
    plot(x=data$x,y=data$y, col=data$group)
    model = lm(y~x, data=data)
    summary(model) 
}



#Scenario 2: The training data in each class came from a mixture of 10 
#low-variance Gaussian distributions, with individual means themselves
#distributed as Gaussian.
scenario2 = function () {
    var = 0.2 # low variance
    n_groups = 10
    m = mixed_dists(N, n_groups, var=var)
    x = m[[1]]
    group = m[[2]]
    y = mixed_dists(N, n_groups, var=var)[[1]]
    data = matrix(c(x,y, group), nrow=N, ncol=3)
    colnames(data) = c("x", "y", "group")
    data = data.frame(data)
    plot(x=data$x,y=data$y, col=data$group)
    model = lm(y~x, data=data)
    summary(model)
}
# scenario1()
# scenario2()
```

So basically the data in scenario 1 is cleanly separated in 2 classes and the data in scenario 2 has about 10 clusters and can't be cleanly separated using a straight line. Indeed, running the linear model on both scenarios it can be seen that on average it will apply better to scenario 1 than to scenario 2.